# Does anyone know of a website with stud framing diagrams?

Tags: framing

Does anyone know of a website with stud framing diagrams for various example rooms e.g. bathroom showing fixtures, kitchen showing appliances, and other various rooms in a house? There are home improvement websites with text descriptions but they are  not quite as useful without diagrams. Obviously all diagrams will be with limitations but generalized ideas can be really helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, resource recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Ok Daniel Thanks I wasn't aware of that. Is that specified somewhere in the user rules

Comment: Yes: [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and, more specifically, [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions). But, do keep those questions coming: I'm sure you have good ones (and good answers to boot).